# Python: declaring dictionaries with keys taken from iterators

Tags: python, dictionary

I am a Python newbie and am struggling with reorganising data contained in nested dictionaries. The original data are like this:

```
['period_1': {'metric_1':{'person_1': 0, 'person_2': 1}, 
{'metric_2': {'person_1': 2, 'person_2': 3}}, 'period_2' :{ ...}
```

What I want to get to is panel data, with people as the main key, followed by periods, followed by metrics. Like this:

```
{'person_1': {'period_1': {'metric_1': 0, 'metric_2': 2}, 'period_2':
{'metric_1': 4, 'metric_2': 6}, 'period_2'{ ... }}, 'person_2': { ...}
```

What I tried so far (the dictionary `allUsers` is going to be the place where I store my reorganised data. It already has persons' IDs as keys, and empty dicts as values):

```
allUsers = {'pippo':{}, 'pluto':{}}

for t in range (len (periods)):
for user in allUsers:
    allUsers[user][t] = {}
period = periods[t]
for metric in period:
    for person in period[metric]:
        allUsers[person][t] = {metric: period[metric][person]}
```

For some reason, this does not work. It only stores one of the two metrics.

```
>>> allUsers
{'pippo': {0: {'metric1': 1}, 1: {'metric1': 1}},
'pluto': {0: {'metric1': 2}, 1: {'metric1': 1}}}
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Check your indentation after `for t in range(len(periods)):`; next code block should be indented in order for the loop to work correclty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that for every new period/metric you find for a person, you are creating a new dictionary and adding to `allUsers[person][t]` in the line -

```
allUsers[person][t] = {metric: period[metric][person]}
```

Hence it only comes once. You actually want to add a new key/value if `t` already exists in `allUsers` . Example -

```
for metric in period:
    for person in period[metric]:
        allUsers[person][t][metric] = period[metric][person]
```

---

But assuming `periods` is a dictionary , you can simplify this using [`dict.setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault). Example -

```
result = {}
for period, value in periods.items():
    for metric, v in value.items():
        for person,val in v.items():
            result.setdefault(person,{}).setdefault(period,{}).set(metric,val)
```

Comment: My reputation is not high enough to upvote your answer, but you did solve it for me, thanks. But I do not understand: when I start, `allUsers` is a dict of (empty) dicts, so it is two levels deep. The line `allUsers[person][t][metric] = period[metric][person] ` creates a new third-level dict, _and_ it populates it on the fly?

Comment: no you create the third level dict in the line - `for user in allUsers: allUsers[user][t] = {}` . The line - `allUsers[person][t][metric] = period[metric][person]` just populates the third level dict.

Comment: @AlbertoCottica You accepted the other answer (not mine). Just FYI.

Answer (score 0):

You're iterating over periods, metrics and persons, so the composite key [person][period] is not going to be unique for each iteration step. When you assign to that key you overwrite whatever was there previously, i.e. the previous metric dictionary.